# How to subtract one stack from another in FIJI (ImageJ)?

Tags: image-processing, image-manipulation, imagej, fiji, imagej-hyperstack

Is there a way of how to subtract one stack of images from another stack using FIJI (ImageJ)?

To be more specific, I would like to find a quick way for such a subtraction, where first image of the first stack is subtracted from the first image of the second stack. Then second image of the first stack is subtracted from the second image of the second stack and so on.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use *Process > Image Calculator...* Specify the stacks and pick subtract in the following dialog to obtain the result. A pop up will ask if you'd like to process all images in the stack, click Yes.

If a rolling subtraction on a single stack is required (subtract i - 1 frame from frame i) use *Analyze > Multi Kymograph > Stack Difference*